# Run a Macro When New Data is Pasted into the Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, events

I'm very new to VBA and trying to figure the below out.

I want my sub to run whenever new data is pasted (or the value is changed) in cell A1 in the CB worksheet.

The second code works perfectly when its ran alone. However, after inserting the first code to run the macro once A1 is change, I get "Run-time error '91: Object variable or with block variable not set" error message.
The error is triggered at this code line "SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = U.Offset(-1, 0)"

How can I make the second macro run once something is pasted or change in cell A1 ?

1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB").UsedRange.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
       Call LoopandIfStatement
    End If

End Sub
```

2.

```
Sub LoopandIfStatement()

Dim SHT As Worksheet
Dim I As Long
Dim O As Long
Dim U As Range

Set SHT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB")
MyLr = SHT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To MyLr

    If IsEmpty(SHT.Range("a" & I).Value) = False Then
        Set U = SHT.Range("A" & I)
        SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = SHT.Range("A" & I).Value
    Else
        SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = U.Offset(-1, 0)
    End If

Next I

For O = 2 To MyLr
    If SHT.Range("g" & O).Value = "Closing Balance" Then
        SHT.Range("l" & O).Value = SHT.Range("j" & O).Value
    End If
Next O

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to step through the code with `F8`key. Maybe what's going on is that the value of variable `I` is 1 and the offset `-1` returns `0` but without looking at your current data, it's difficult to tell

Comment: If the `Else`  block is entered on the first iteration, then `U` hasn't been set yet. Also be careful when offsetting by `-1` as there is no row 0, as already pointed out.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz the offset is basically saying that if cell A3 has a value, copy it into K3. If its empty, copy the cell above it into K3 and repeat. the stand alone code works perfectly and gets me the results I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the crash is caused by the Change event being triggered by a change initiated by your second procedure. Try suppressing events while that procedure is executed.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call LoopAndIfStatement
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: I believe I solved the problem by adding an On Error GoTo ABC above the code below. However, my procedure is not being triggered when a change events occurs. Thoughts?

`
 Else
        SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = U.Offset(-1, 0)
`

Comment: Worksheet event procedures must be placed in the code sheet of the worksheet in which the event occurs.